# Input Field update in PageBlockTable using Custom Controller in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I update the inputfield values in the pageblocktable by using commandbutton?

[image: Page Block]

When I click the add new button the values will be display in the below table.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Events">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Events Section">
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.name}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.Event_Type__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.Events__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.No_s__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.Rate__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.Tax__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!event.Discount__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Final_Rate__c}"/>

 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
 <div align="center">
 <apex:commandButton value="Add"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"/>
 </div>
 <apex:pageblockTable value="{!event}" var="even">
 <apex:column headerValue="Event Type"/>
  <apex:column headerValue="Events"/>
   <apex:column headerValue="No.S"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Rate"/>
     <apex:column headerValue="Tax%"/>
      <apex:column headerValue="Discount%"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Final Rate"/>
 </apex:pageblockTable>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
 <div align="center">
    <apex:commandButton value="Save"/>
 </div>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Contoller::

```
public class Events {
private final Event__c event;

//public list<Event__c > even {get; set;}

  public Event__c getevent() {
        return event;
    }
  public PageReference save() {
        update event;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use [Action Support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) or [Action Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) and use `rerender` attribute on the command button to refresh the pageblock table asynchronously.

Comment: If you add your VF page code here, we would be able to help you better, but you should be good with the above comment to kick start "what you are looking for'! :)

Comment: Best [inline edit example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_inline_editing.htm)